# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP arithmetic - QuerySyntaxException

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to add a `@Modifying` method in the spring-jpa interface with the following

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("update Contact cc set cc.bar=?2 where cc.foo = ?1 AND cc.createdTime>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '60' minute")
public Contact setFixedBarFor(String foo, boolean bar);
```

But I get the following exception,..

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: interval near line 1, column 136 [update Contact cc set cc.foo=?2 where cc.bar = ?1 AND cc.createdTime>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '20' minute]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:288)
```

**Note:**
The following works:

```
update Contact cc set cc.bar=?2 where cc.foo = ?1 AND cc.createdTime>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

update Contact cc set cc.bar=?2 where cc.foo = ?1 AND cc.createdTime>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-1
```

I want arithmetic inbuilt into it, and **not** sure what is it, that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the same problem as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720674/oracle-jpa-querying-with-interval)?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing the following

```
update Contact cc set cc.bar=?2 where cc.foo = ?1 AND cast((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (1/24)) as timestamp) between cc.createdTime and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
```

Thanks @Burhan for [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720674/oracle-jpa-querying-with-interval) pointer and this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18677545/234110).